# Django : Adding pagination and searchbar to filter the listing of a FormView (ClassView)

Tags: django, class, search, view, pagination

I use a FormView from the ClassView available in Django to upload and display listing of files. In the FormView there is no get_queryset and pagination methods to list easily data. So I used the "get_context_data" and the "get" method combined with a pagination method that I wrote to do my file table listing.This part works

I want to add a searchbar to filter the results and change the pagination too. However I do not manage to add this fonctionnality to my code. It can filter, but when I click to switch to the next page it removes the filter ans show all the results.

I think that the code is not well structured between the "get_context_data", "get" and "pagination" and I do not see how to change it.

Can anyone help me ? There is no interest to look to the post method of the code, it is to upload the files.

##### views.py

```
class DocumentUpload(FormView) :
    model   = Documents
    template_name = 'upload/upload.html'
    form_class = FilesForm

    def pagination(self, page_number, list_files):

        paginator = Paginator(list_files, 10)

        try:
            list_files_page = paginator.page(page_number)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            list_files_page = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            list_files_page = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        return list_files_page

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(DocumentUpload, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        qs = self.model.objects.all().order_by('-Timestamp')

        search = self.request.GET.get('search')

        if search :
            qs = qs.filter(Filenamebeforeindex__icontains=search)
        
        context['list_all_files'] = qs

        return context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        # WE LOAD THE CONTEXT
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)

        if self.model.objects.all().exists() : # IF THE MODEL IS EMPTY THERE IS NO INTEREST TO RUN THAT

            # Pagination
            page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
            list_files_page = self.pagination(page_number=page, list_files=context['list_all_files'])

            max_ID      = context['list_all_files'].latest('Id').Uuid
            fileUUID    = request.GET.get('fileUUID', max_ID)
            file        = self.model.objects.get(Uuid = fileUUID)
            encodedstring, extension = FileQueryDisplay(file=file).encode_data_file_from_Azure()

            # CHARGE THE CONTEXT
            context['page']             = page
            context['list_files_page']  = list_files_page
            context['fileUUID']         = fileUUID
            context['extension']        = extension
            context["encodedstring"]    = str(encodedstring)[1:].replace("'","")

        else :
    
            pass

        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        # WE LOAD THE CONTEXT
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # WE GET THE LIST OF FILES FROM THE POST METHOD
        form = self.form_class(request.POST, request.FILES)
        files_selected = request.FILES.getlist('Filename') # create a list of files

        if form.is_valid():

            for file in files_selected :

                # DEFINE THE DATA OF THE FILE
                file = FileDefinitionBeforeUpload(file=file).file_information()

                # GET THE CONTENT OF THE FILE
                content = file.read()
                file_io =  BytesIO(content)

                # THE UPLOAD TO THE BLOB
                AzureBlobFile   = AzureBlob()
                blob_client     = AzureBlobFile.blob_client(blob_name= file.name)
                blob_client.upload_blob(data=file_io)

                user = self.request.session.get('user')

                newfile = self.model(    User                = user.get('email'), 
                                        Filename            = file.name, 
                                        Filenamebeforeindex = file.previous_name, 
                                        Size                = file.size, 
                                        Format              = file.extension,
                                        # ID_Customer     = id_contrat, 
                                        Url                 = blob_client.url)
                newfile.save()
        else :

            form = FilesForm()

        # CHARGE THE CONTEXT FOR THE TEMPLATE
        context['form'] = form

        return redirect('upload')
```

##### html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

{%  load static %} 

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- Boxicons CSS -->
    <link   href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.1/css/boxicons.min.css' 
            rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">

</head>

<body>

    {{ encodedstring | json_script:'fileDATA' }} 
    {{ extension | json_script:'fileEXT'}}
    
    <div class="upload-app">
        <div class="upload-in">
            <h2>Upload</h2>

            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}

                <button type="submit" id="submitupload">Upload</button>
            </form>
        
            <div class="fileselect">
                <p>Selected files :</p>
                    <div id="fileselect"></div>
            </div>     
        </div> 
        <div class="listfiles">

            <h2>Files Uploaded</h2>

            <form method="GET" action="">
                <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search" value="{{ request.GET.q }}">
                <button  type="submit"  value="">Submit</button>
            </form>

            <table id="customers">
                <tr>
                    <th>Filename</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Size</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>

                {% for file in list_files_page %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ file.Filenamebeforeindex }}</td>
                    <td>{{ file.Timestamp | date:'d.m.Y H:i'}}</td>
                    <td>{{ file.Size| filesizeformat}}</td>
                    <td class="iconsColumn">
                        <a href="{% url 'download' file.Uuid %}">
                            <i class='bx bxs-download'></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="?page={{ page }}&fileUUID={{ file.Uuid }}">
                            <i class='bx bxs-file-pdf' ></i>
                        </a>
                    </td>>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}

            </table>

            <div class="pagination">
                {% if list_files_page.has_previous %}
                <a class="pagination-action" href="?page=1&fileUUID={{ fileUUID }}">
                    <i class='bx bx-chevrons-left' aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
                <a class="pagination-action" href="?page={{ list_files_page.previous_page_number }}&fileUUID={{ fileUUID }}">
                    <i class='bx bx-chevron-left' aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
                {% endif %}
                {% for num in list_files_page.paginator.page_range %}
                    {% if list_files_page.number == num %}
                        <span class="pagination-number pagination-current">{{ num }}</span>
                    {% elif num > list_files_page.number|add:'-3' and num < list_files_page.number|add:'3' %}
                        <a class="pagination-number" href="?page={{ num }}&fileUUID={{ fileUUID }}">{{ num }}</a>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                {% if list_files_page.has_next %}
                    <a class="pagination-action" href="?page={{ list_files_page.next_page_number }}&fileUUID={{ fileUUID }}">
                        <i class='bx bx-chevron-right' aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a class="pagination-action" href="?page={{ list_files_page.paginator.num_pages }}&fileUUID={{ fileUUID }}">
                        <i class='bx bx-chevrons-right' aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
    </div>

    <div id="pdfdisplay">

    </div>
```